# Sum values in specific rows based on whether the row has a value that belongs to a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have a table that has several metrics (example: revenue, cost, etc.) for about a hundred different accounts. I can't modify this sheet because it gets auto-updated by a different group.

On a summary page, I want to be able to pick a metric, say revenue (Cell C11), and specify a set of accounts (Named Range C12:C13). The result (Cell C16) should be the sum of the revenues of all the specified accounts.

For just one account, I had:

```
=SUM(IF(B3:B8=SelectedAccount, IF(C2:D2=SelectedMetric, C3:D8)))
```

But I want to be able to do this for multiple accounts. The list of accounts is variable, and is around 30 accounts, so can't just do chain together a couple of the above formula.

Here's the simplified example, in image format. (Result should be 12).
[image: Simplified Example]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason you want to do it this way in particular? Are you open to using a pivot table instead?

Comment: How about checkboxes instead of the Accounts to Include field? Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SFwTw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(INDEX(C2:D7,0,MATCH(SelectedMetric,MetricHeaders,0))*IFERROR(MATCH(AccountNames,SelectedAccount,0)>0,0))`

Where:

- `MATCH(SelectedMetric,MetricHeaders,0))` - looks for the column number of the selected metric
- `INDEX(C2:D7,0,MATCH(...))` - select the desired column from the table
- `MATCH(AccountNames,SelectedAccount,0)>0` - selects rows which are in the selected accounts
- `IFERROR(MATCH(...)>0,0)` - converts errors to `0`

Similarly to the formula in the original question, this is also an array formula, need to be entered by `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`